# Qt deploy application in Windows needed dlls

Tags: c++, windows, qt, deployment, mingw

There is a tool in the mingw compiller directory that when called with the output exe file as parameter, it copies all needed dlls to the current directory. I can't remember the name and I cannot find it on the internet. Does anyone know what it is called?

Answer (score 3):

The tool is called windeployqt.